# Django: Filter request results to only contain data related to the requesting user

Tags: python, django, rest, request, sails.js

I'm a Django beginner (though I do have experience in web development using Sails.js + Angular) so bear with me.

I have an existing application that uses REST API in communicating between Sails.js backend and AngularJS frontend. Now, we've found the backend to be unsuited for our purposes, and we're going to swap to using Django in near-future. Sails.js automatically creates the REST methods for the controllers while Django doesn't, so I suppose I'm going to use something like Django Rest Framework to create the API.

So yeah, I've found corresponding features for most things. The on thing I haven't found yet is a replacement for a Sails.js feature called "policies". They are functions that can be executed on queries to certain controller actions, and can be defined as model-specific, model-controller action-specific, and request type specific. For example, you can have an "`authAccess`" policy that checks that the user of a request is authenticated, and the policy gets executed before the actual requested controller method gets executed. You can also use these to modify request objects before passing them to the controller. Now to my actual problem:

Let's say I have a `User` model that has a many-to-one relation with another model, let's call it `Book`, meaning a user can own many books, but a book can only have one owner. Goody good. Now, we have a logged-in user that is making a query to find all of his books. He makes a GET request to `/book`. I want to ensure that the returned `Book` objects are filtered so that ONLY HIS BOOKS are returned.

So basically in Sails I was able to write a policy that altered the request parameters to be like `{user: loggedInUser}` so the resulting `Book` results were automatically filtered. This was handy, since I was able to use the same policy to filter other models, too, like `DVD` or `Friend` or whatnot. My question is - what would be the best way to implement the same functionality in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user

Most likely you are better off overwriting the get_queryset method in a model viewset. And you can make this a generic approach by creating a base class for your views, something like:

```
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets, mixins, generics


class OwnerModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the records
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

All your model viewset classes can inherit from that class. It would require the foreign key field to be always named "user" though. If that is not the case here is a slightly hacky way how you could find a foreign key field to the User table. Use with care.

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey 
from accounts.models import User

def _get_related_user(self, obj):
    '''
     Search for FK to user model and return field name or False if no FK.
     This can lead to wrong results when the model has more than one user FK.
    '''
    for f in self.model._meta.fields:
        if isinstance(f, ForeignKey) and f.rel.to == User:
            return f.name
    return False
```